# Remove function is not working in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Anybody suggest me, where I went wrong?And also I need some explanation about the script I used for editing and removing because I just referred some materials and used that code without understanding.Can anyone explain this?

Code:

```
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Salary</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="faculty in facultymembers">
                <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.id}}</span><input
                    type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.id"></td>
                <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.name}}</span><input
                    type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.name"></td>
                <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.salary}}</span><input
                    type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.salary"></td>
                <td><button ng-hide="editmode"
                        ng-click="editmode=true;editfaculty(faculty)">EDIT</button>
                    <button ng-show="editmode" ng-click="editmode=false">DONE</button></td>
                <td><button ng-click="removefaculty($index)">REMOVE</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
        app.controller("mycont", function($scope) {
            $scope.facultymembers = [];
            $scope.addfaculty = function(faculty) {
                $scope.facultymembers.push(faculty);
                $scope.faculty = {};

            };
            $scope.editfaculty = function(index) {
                $scope.editing = $scope.facultymembers.Indexof(index)
            };
            $scope.removefaculty = function(index) {
                console.log(index);
                $scope.facultymembers.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Indexof` should be replaced by `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed **track by $index**:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.facultymembers = [{
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Test',
        'salary': 2000
      }];
      $scope.addfaculty = function(faculty) {
        $scope.facultymembers.push(faculty);
        $scope.faculty = {};

      };
      $scope.editfaculty = function(index) {
        $scope.editing = $scope.facultymembers.Indexof(index)
      };
      $scope.removefaculty = function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        $scope.facultymembers.splice(index, 1);
      }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<table border="1" class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Salary</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="faculty in facultymembers track by $index">
            <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.id}}</span><input type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.id"></td>
            <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.name}}</span><input type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.name"></td>
            <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.salary}}</span><input type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.salary"></td>
            <td><button ng-hide="editmode" ng-click="editmode=true;editfaculty($index)">EDIT</button>
              <button ng-show="editmode" ng-click="editmode=false">DONE</button></td>
            <td><button ng-click="removefaculty($index)">REMOVE</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: And another doubt.For editing the data, in table I gave editfaculty(faculty) but in script function I gave $scope.editfaculty = function(index).Why we are not using $scope.editfaculty = function(faculty)

Comment: @Pravin because its better to pass the index than the whole object.